# Pandas: How to count individual words in each row in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks like something like this:

```
sentences
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'and', 'this', 'one', 'as', 'well']
['this', 'is', 'another', 'sentence', 'and', 'this', 'sentence', 'looks', 'like', 'other', 'sentences']
```

I'm trying to calculate the count of each word in each row, and store them in a way that I can use it easily when needed. So far I've failed, and I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using df.column_name[.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Counter` with `DataFrame` constructor, but for missing values get `NaNs`:

```
from collections import Counter

print (type(df.loc[0, 'sentences']))
<class 'list'>

df1 = pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for x in df['sentences']])
print (df1)
     a  and  another   as  is  like  looks  one  other  sentence  sentences  \
0  1.0    1      NaN  1.0   1   NaN    NaN  1.0    NaN         1        NaN   
1  NaN    1      1.0  NaN   1   1.0    1.0  NaN    1.0         2        1.0   

   this  well  
0     2   1.0  
1     2   NaN
```

If need replace `NaNs` to `0` add [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for x in df['sentences']]).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   a  and  another  as  is  like  looks  one  other  sentence  sentences  \
0  1    1        0   1   1     0      0    1      0         1          0   
1  0    1        1   0   1     1      1    0      1         2          1   

   this  well  
0     2     1  
1     2     0
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response! Is it possible to do that without rearranging them alphabetically?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because `DataFrame` constructor sort it :(

Comment: Well, it seems we can't have everything :D thanks again!